# How does the different behavior of the unless- and "if !" statement influence the range-operator in scalar context?

Tags: perl, operator-precedence, associativity

On http://novosial.org/perl/one-liner/ I found the following two one-liners. The outputs are different because the `unless` statement is different from `if !` ( due to the associativity and precedence rules ).

```
cat file:  
foo  



bar
```

```
perl -ne 'print unless /^$/../^$/' file  
foo  
bar
```

```
perl -ne 'print if ! /^$/../^$/' file  
foo  

bar
```

How does the different behavior of the `if !`-statement make the second one-liner output one blank line?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the linked article says, it's a matter of associativity and precedence...

`print unless /^$/../^$/` is equivalent to `print if !(/^$/../^$/)`

`print if ! /^$/../^$/` is equivalent to `print if (!/^$/)../^$/`

Note that the first negates the range expression, while the second negates the range's beginning condition, but not the range itself.

Answer (score 4):

The answer, IMHO, is that there is no `if !` statement in Perl: There is an `if` statement and there is a `!` operator. The `!` operator does not bind to `if`; it operates on its argument. If you start thinking in these terms, your life will be easier.

So, in your case, you have,

```
do_something() unless something;
```

and

```
do_something() if something-else;
```

Let's put in the normally invisible parentheses:

```
do_something() unless ( something );
```

and

```
do_something() if ( something-else );
```

In this case, you tried to write `something-else` so that the truth value of that condition is equivalent to the truth of `something`, but failed to take into account the fact that `!` operator binds tightly.

That is why there is `not`.

Try

```
perl -ne 'print if not /^$/../^$/' file
```

See [`not` in perldoc perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Logical-Not):

> Unary `not` returns the logical negation of the expression to its right. It's the equivalent of `!` except for the very low precedence.

Answer (score 1):

The range test will return true up to the time that the 2nd operand is true. It will then return false on the next call.

This snippet tells us what the range operator is returning

```
perl -ne "$x= ( ! /^$/../^$/ ) ; print qq/$x : $_/" range_test.TXT
```

which produces

```
1 : foo
2E0 :
 :
 :
1 : bar
```

So the first blank line generates a true response, the next one false